# What do we lose by going from self adjoint to essentially self adjoint

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, quantum-mechanics

I am reading Glimm and Jaffe to try and get a more formal understanding of quantum mechanics and they keep insisting that operators are essentially self-adjoint.  I understand from QM we want some form of hermitian/self-adjoint-ness.  However Why do we not lose anything important when merely looking at essentially self adjoint?

Comment: The closure of an essentially self-adjoint operator is self-adjoint. So you theoretically have _more_ information when looking at an essentially self-adjoint operator - since now you are also being told a domain that is (possibly) physically interesting (although in practice it might be difficult to calculate the closure). That this is nice is more evident in representation theory of $*$-algebras when you have different essentially self-adjoint operators with the same domain (their closures will have domains differing from one another).

Comment: Not really your Question, but it is often easy to find a domain of e.s.a. , while difficult (and unnecessary) to find the exact full domain of s.a.

Comment: In addition to the two helpful comments: Self-adjointness defined in terms of domains which can be quite elusive to compute exactly is not very intuitive, at least to me. A better definition, via Stone's Theorem, is the property one needs for a symmetric operator $A$ so the Cauchy problem (or IVP) for the differential equation $x'=iAx$ is well-posed. For e.s.a., Nelson's analytic vector theorem gives a similar, more intuitive (to me) definition.